# Spark UDF type mismatch error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to write a UDF to convert a timestamp into an integer representing the hour of the week.  I'm easily able to accomplish this with SparkSql like this.

[image]

I have many UDFs in our code with this exact syntax but this one is trying a type mismatch error.  I also tried invoking my UDF with `col("session_ts_start")` but that also failed to work.

```scala
import spark.implicits._
import java.sql.Timestamp
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

def getHourOfWeek() = udf(
    (ts: Timestamp) => unix_timestamp(ts)
)

val dDF = df.withColumn("hour", getHourOfWeek()(df("session_ts_start")))
dDF.show()

<console>:154: error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.sql.Timestamp
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
           (ts: Timestamp) => unix_timestamp(ts)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`unix_timestamp` is a SQL function. It [operates on `Columns`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@unix_timestamp(s:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) not external values:

```scala
def unix_timestamp(s: Column): Column
```

and it cannot be used in UDF.

> I'm trying (...) to convert a timestamp into an integer representing the hour of the week

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{date_format, hour}

def getHourOfWeek(c: Column) =
  // https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html
  (date_format(c, "u").cast("integer") - 1) * 24 + hour(c)

val df = Seq("2017-03-07 01:00:00").toDF("ts").select($"ts".cast("timestamp"))

df.select(getHourOfWeek($"ts").alias("hour")).show
```

```
+----+
|hour|
+----+
|  25|
+----+
```

Another possible solution:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{next_day, date_sub}

def getHourOfWeek2(c: Column) = ((
  c.cast("bigint") - 
  date_sub(next_day(c, "Mon"), 7).cast("timestamp").cast("bigint")
) / 3600).cast("int")

df.select(getHourOfWeek2($"ts").alias("hour"))
```

```
+----+
|hour|
+----+
|  25|
+----+
```

**Note**: Neither solution handles daylight saving time or other date / time subtleties.